# List manipulation in F#

Tags: list, recursion, f#

What I'm hoping to make this function do is:

1. Generate a list of random integers of length specified by count
2. Generate another random number to replace first element of list
3. Sort the list
4. Split list in half, discarding second half
5. Discard first element of list
6. Repeat 2-5 unless list is empty

What I have so far (but not working) is below.  What is the matter with it?

```
let go count =
    let rec cut l = 
        if List.length l = 0 then l
        printfn "%A" l
        let list = System.Random().Next(100)::List.tail l
        let cut list = 
            let firstHalf= list |> Seq.take (List.length list / 2) |> Seq.toList
            firstHalf
        let listSorted = List.sort list
        cut (List.tail listSorted)
    let r = System.Random()
    let list1 = List.init count (fun numbers -> r.Next(100))
    printfn "List = %A" list1
    cut list1
```

Comment: I don't know F#, but it seems obviuous that you pack too much in a single function. Split the task in smaller functions, which are much easier to get right, test them, and only then use them to assemble your go function. This makes it easier for others to help you, too.

Comment: @Landei Really I can't see the point of making smaller functions and use them once. Reading functional code is not the same as reading OOP code. Little functions are using only when they are being used several times, that's part of purity in my opinion.

Comment: Which school teaches F#?

Comment: It's part of a Languages and Computations course at Seattle University.  Course isn't focused on F# specifically, just this assignment.

Comment: @nCdy: This is not a question of OO vs functional: Your brain can only focus on a certain amount of data. Everything you can get "out of your way" helps to concentrate on the real problems. If you think too many small functions clutter your code, you can still put them back in the big function later - but only when it is already *working*.

Comment: @Landei Agreed here, sure when it's already working. That's really hard to debug something complex.

Answer (score 7):

A few tips:

- Don't test if a list is empty by List.length L = 0. Each test will take as long as the amount of elements in the list. Test with pattern matching instead, that's (almost) instantanteous:
- Don't instantiate a new instance of a random number generator each time your `cut` function is called: `let list = System.Random()...`. Doing that means that you're likely to get the same numbers (each instantiaion seeds the generator with the current system time). Just move your declaration `r = System.Random()` up a bit, and use that generator throughout your code.

example:

```
let rec cut l =
    match l with
    | [] -> // the list is empty, end the recursion here
    | head::tail -> // the list consists of the head element and the rest
                    // you can refer to head and tail in your code here
                    let newlist = r.next(100) :: tail
```

- You're declaring a function called 'cut' inside your recursive 'cut' function, which means that the last call to 'cut' in your recursive function actually calls the non-recursive one you defined inside. Use different names there.
- You've written 'if List.length l = 0 then l', which (apart from not using a pattern match) also presents a problem: an 'if' in F# is an expression, like the `?` operator in C#. In C# that would mean something like

  `(l.Count == 0) ? l : //other case missing! error! danger!`
- Another tip: once your list is sorted, you don't need to sort again each time you add a new random element. You can write code that inserts a new element in a sorted list that would be more efficient than adding an element and sorting afterwards. I'll leave the insert-into-sorted-list as an excercise.

I hope these tips are useful.

Answer (score 2):

here is my try...

```
let go count = 
    System.Random() |> fun rnd ->  // With ranomizer ... (we will need it)
        let rec repeat = function  // So we got recursion 
            | x::xs when xs.Length <> 1 ->       // while we have head and tail
                printfn "%A" xs
                rnd .Next(100) :: (List.tail xs) // Add random value
                |> Seq.sort                      // Sort
                |> Seq.take( abs(xs.Length /2) ) // Make a half
                |> Seq.skip 1                    // Remove first (just skip)
                |> List.ofSeq                    // Make the list
                |> repeat                        // So and repeat
            | x::xs -> printfn "%A" xs
            | _ -> ()              // If we have no head and tail
        repeat <| List.init count (fun _ -> rnd.Next(100)) // do it with our random list
```

Comment: Could you please comment on the second line? (System.Random() |> fun rnd ->) I am not sure I completely understand what is going on there. Could you not just create "let rnd = System.Random()"?

Comment: @Oldrich Svec it's a Pipe + lambda (I'm using System.Random() as parameter for lambda function) Yes let rnd = System.Random() is the same but my rnd will work only inside this lambda. As far as we got no other functions there there is no point using it, but I like to use it alike sql "With" style.

Comment: addition : it's not IDisposable alike using for example ( using <| new SqlConnection(sql)  <| fun X -> ) but I'm following the style. Instead of using right pipe because I need left part for right (not right part for left).

Comment: @Danny yes, my fault, I tough x::xs is only when we have a head and tail, but it's even holds one element. Added workaround but maybe I'm missing something else, I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is as simple as making functions for each of your statements.

```
let rnd = new System.Random()

let genList n = 
    [for i = 0 to n-1 do yield rnd.Next()]

let replaceHead v lst = match lst with
                        | [] -> []
                        | (x::xs) -> (v::xs)

let splitInHalf lst = 
    let len = (lst |> List.length) / 2
    let rec loop n lst = 
        match (n,lst) with
        | 0,_ -> []
        | _,[] -> []
        | _,(x::xs) -> x :: (loop (n-1) xs)
    loop len lst


let start n = 
    let lst = genList n
    let rec loop l = 
        match l with
        | [] -> []
        | ls -> match ls |> replaceHead (rnd.Next()) 
                         |> List.sort 
                         |> splitInHalf with
                | [] -> []
                | xs -> xs |> List.tail |> loop

    loop lst

start 1
```

Comment: I want to print the list each time it is sorted.  This syntax is still very foreign to me.  Why can't I just put in |> printfn "Now: %A" under the List.sort without getting errors?

Comment: Because after List.sort we have |> splitInHalf which need a list as parameter.. where as printfn returns unit... what you can do in place of |> List.sort is this... |> (fun l -> printfn "Now %A" l; l |> List.sort)

Answer (score 0):

It does look like homework :)
But here is my take on it:

```
#light

// Create random integer sequence
let random_integers_of_length l  = 
    (l, new System.Random()) 
        |> Seq.unfold (fun (c, rnd) -> if c = 0 then None else Some (rnd.Next(), (c-1, rnd))) 
        |> Seq.cache

let rec mutate numbers =
    printfn "%A" (List.ofSeq numbers);                          // pretty print the list
    match numbers with                                  
    | _ when (Seq.length numbers) <= 1 -> printfn "Done.."      // if length is 1 or 0 we can stop.
    | _ ->
        numbers
            |> Seq.skip 1                                       // discard first element 
            |> Seq.append (random_integers_of_length 1)         // append random number at the start 
            |> Seq.sort                                         // sort 
            |> Seq.take ((Seq.length numbers) / 2)              // take the first half, ignore the rest
            |> Seq.skip 1                                       // discard first element 
            |> mutate                                           // do it again.
```